# Creating service to start

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've installed Virtuoso and I want to create a service so this service can start with the OS. To start Virtuoso normaly I go to the directory `cd /usr/local/var/lib/virtuoso/db` and run `virtuoso-t -f`. This command has to be executed inside the directory I've mentioned otherwise it does not read the config files. So I created the script at `/etc/init.d/virtuoso`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Virtuoso        Startup script for the Openlink Virtuoso
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

prog="virtuoso"
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/virtuoso.lock
RETVAL=0

start() {
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        cd /usr/local/var/lib/virtuoso/db/ | virtuoso-t -f
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch ${lockfile}
        return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc $prog -TERM
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f ${lockfile} ${pidfile}
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  status)
    # status -p $pidfile && exit 0 || exit $?
    status $prog
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $prog {start|stop|restart|status}"
    RETVAL=2
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

But the service complains that it is not finding the command `virtuoso-t`. If I create a script to start manually without `service start virtuoso` it works. But if I call the script inside the `/etc/init.d/virtuoso` does not work.

Any clue? Thanks

```
# service virtuoso status
● virtuoso.service - SYSV: The Openlink Virtuoso is a high-performance object-relational SQL database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/virtuoso; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-03-09 11:17:25 EST; 28s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 10905 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/virtuoso start (code=exited, status=127)

Mar 09 11:17:25 irodsprodvm.ebioscience.amc.nl systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: The Openlink Virtuoso is a high-performance object-relational SQL database....
Mar 09 11:17:25 irodsprodvm.ebioscience.amc.nl virtuoso[10905]: Starting virtuoso: /etc/rc.d/init.d/virtuoso: line 19: virtuoso-t: command not found
Mar 09 11:17:25 irodsprodvm.ebioscience.amc.nl systemd[1]: virtuoso.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
Mar 09 11:17:25 irodsprodvm.ebioscience.amc.nl systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: The Openlink Virtuoso is a high-performance object-relational SQL database..
Mar 09 11:17:25 irodsprodvm.ebioscience.amc.nl systemd[1]: Unit virtuoso.service entered failed state.
Mar 09 11:17:25 irodsprodvm.ebioscience.amc.nl systemd[1]: virtuoso.service failed.
Warning: virtuoso.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed. Added this line on the begin of the script

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```